# Install OpenCV for python building the source or with apt-get?

Tags: python, linux, opencv, apt-get

I'm working with OpenCV using Python on Linux.
I always installed OpenCV building the the Source with make. As you know there are many guides online which all say pretty much the same things.
Now i found some guys which say to install OpenCV using apt-get with the command

> sudo apt-get install python-opencv

Which are the difference between the two methods ? Can i just use the apt-get command ? 
I looked around for an answer, but i still don't understand if i can avoid building OpenCV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, it's much easier to use the `apt-get` variant.

Some drawbacks are, that you might not get the most recent version hence the `apt-get` package isn't updated as fast as the sources are. Furthermore you'll have a higher level of control according to modules that are going to be installed and the compile parameters, when using the "`make` way".

If you just want an easy way, use the `apt-get install` version. If you want control, flexibility and the most recent version, use the `make` version and compile the source code according to your needs.